# Is it possible to shift the numerical results in order to compare it with the analytical solution?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, lattice-boltzmann-methods

I'm using lattice Boltzmann method (LBM) to do simulation of flow in a pipe. The diameter of the pipe is 0.02 m and its height is 0.1 m. I put a parabolic velocity profile at the inlet:

$$\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{r},t) = \bar{u}(t) \Bigg(2 - \frac{2|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_{C}|^{2}}{R^{2}}\Bigg)$$

Where $R$ is the radius of the pipe, $\mathbf{r}_{C}$ is the position of the center of inlet circle, which in my case is: $\mathbf{r}_{C} = (0,0,0)$ and the axis of the pipe is oriented at the z-direction. Finally for $u_{max}(t)$, I have:

$$\bar{u}(t) = \frac{u_{avg}}{2} + \frac{u_{amp}}{2}\sin{(\omega t)}$$

Where $u_{avg} = 0.000124289772727275$ $\frac{\text{m}}{\text{s}}$ and $u_{amp} = 0.00004143$ $\frac{\text{m}}{\text{s}}$ and $\omega = 2 \pi$. This funny numbers for $u_{avg}$ and $u_{amp}$ are chosen because of keeping the Reynolds number at 1. In fact, for density and viscosity, I have: $\rho = 1056$ $\frac{\text{kg}}{\text{m}^{3}}$ and $\mu = 0.0035$ $\text{Pa} \cdot \text{s}$:

$$\text{Re} = \frac{2 \rho R u_{max}}{\mu} = \frac{2 \times 1056 \times 0.01 \times 0.000165719696969700}{0.0035} = 1$$

Note that: $u_{max} = u_{avg} + u_{amp} = 0.000165719696969700$ $\frac{\text{m}}{\text{s}}$.

Because, this is a pipe, I expect to see the same $\bar{u}$ at the outlet after simulation. I run this simulation for 12 seconds in reality, which is equal to 12 cycles of this sinusoidal waveform. My Mach number (i.e. lattice Mach number that has nothing to do with the physical Mach number) and relaxation time as well as my spatio-temporal resolutions are:

$$\text{Mach} = 0.002$$

$$\tau = 0.85$$

$$\Delta x = 0.2 \ \text{mm}$$

$$\Delta t = 1.39 \ \text{ms}$$

Now this the comparison of $\bar{u}(t)$ measured at the outlet versus time:

[image]

The blue curve in the above plot is just the analytical $\bar{u}(t)$ defined above and the orange one is the one that I measured at the outlet. You see that there is a time lag or phase shift between the $\bar{u}(t)$ that I measure at the outlet and the analytical solution. In fact, the reason seems to be because of my initial condition that I start from zero velocity everywhere and my simulation needs sometimes to sync outlet with the inlet. In fact, the time that is needed to  transport information from inlet to outlet could be estimated as:

$$t^{*} = \frac{L}{c_{s}} = \frac{0.1}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}} = 1.20 \ \text{s}$$

As we could see from the plot the initial part of the simulation results that orange curve is still equal to zero is around 1 s, which confirms our above estimation for the time that is needed to carry the information from inlet to outlet. In fact, because of artificial compressibility of the LBM framework, there is a 1.20 time lag between inlet and outlet. I know, by decreasing the Mach number, I could decrease the time lag but this makes my simulations pretty expensive for my actual application. Now, if I look at the end of the signal in the above plot and try to find one cycle of my simulation result and compare it with the one cycle of the analytical solution, I have this plot:

[image]

In fact, I just matched the position of the last peak in my full signal visualization and then plot just the last cycle in the above chart. As you see, if we put the time lag aside, the amplitude and shape of the signal extracted from LBM matches the analytical solution quite well (analytical solution: blue curve and numerical results: orange dashed curve).

So finally my **question**: Am I allowed to match the last the peak of these two signals and claim that: if we put the time lag aside, which is purely an artifact of the LBM, the two signals match quite well and my framework works fine?

Comment: If the simulation model time does not enter explicitly the underlying PDEs and BC then the solution is defined by the initial conditions at some reference time $t_0$ and the time since $t_0$. So the answer to your question should be "yes" although even with a time shift it does not look like a very good match to my eye.

Comment: @MaximUmansky What do you mean the time does not enter explicitly the underlying PDEs and BC? Here I solve the Navier-Stokes equation but obviously with a different approach from conventional FEM or FVM methods by using LBM, so time derivative of velocity shows up actually in the Navier-Stokes equation but my BC at the outlet is just open boundary condition or $P = 0$.

Comment: Flipping @MaximUmansky comment on its head, the Navier-Stokes equations typically have a time-dependent term, so, no, you can't just pull this out without having some effects. Given your pretty tiny lattice Mach number, though, you might get away with it for engineering purposes, though. However, since you have an analytical solution, I wonder why you bother to simulate it, unless you're using this problem as a test of your code.

Comment: @BillBarth It's for testing a code.

Comment: @BillBarth Also, I have the same results with $\text{Re} = 62.5$ and pretty much the time lag goes away.

Comment: @AloneProgrammer, then I say just crank out the time derivative (by hand or in Mathematica, MATLAB, or Maple) and chuck it into the forcing term. That makes it something else you have to code correctly and test, but you always have to write your tests right. (+1 for testing)

Comment: @BillBarth What do you mean crank out the time derivative? I don't have any assumption on removing any time dependency here. Actually, the inertial term of $\rho \frac{\partial \mathbf{u}}{\partial t}$ is there now.

Comment: @AloneProgrammer, replace $u$ by $v=u-\bar{u}$ everywhere and move the boundary conditions mostly to zero and create a bunch of new forcing terms for your problem. On that you'll have to mechanically (with your pen and paper or with a computer tool) "turn the crank", but you can move the trouble to solving a simpler problem and then you can add back the known solution to $v$ after you solve for it. This is basically the Method of Manufactured Solutions (google that) with some computer or hand calculus help.

Comment: All I meant in my original comment is that for an an autonomous system described by differential equations $\partial f / \partial t = F(f)$ (time does not enter the RHS), one can shift the solution in time if the initial condition is shifted to a different initial time. The provided plot suggests that shifting the initial condition to a different time the whole subsequent time-evolution curve is shifted by the same amount, consistent with an autonomous system behavior.

Comment: @MaximUmansky I really appreciate your help if you elaborate it in an answer.